# What's the meaning of FailedWithinSuccess in TestNG?

Tags: testng

https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-exit-codes

[image]

I don't understand the meaning of FailedWithinSuccess. What's the difference between "FailedWithinSuccess" and "Failed"

Comment: When u use the `successPercentage` option along with `invocationCount` in the Test annotation and there is atleast one failure in the test method but above the value of the success percent. if u set invocationcount to 10, success percent to 75 for a test method, fails 1 or 2 times it will show `FailedWithinSuccess`